# Making sense of the foreach

Tags: r

I'm new to paralleling the for loop using foreach and struggle to understand how it works. As an example for the exercise, I created a simple list (input2) based on a dataframe (input). I try to calculate b by looping through h and j.

```
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)
library(dplyr)

input <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(200*200, 0, .5), ncol=200))
input[input <=0] =0
input['X201'] <- seq(from = 0, to = 20, length.out = 10)
input <- input %>% select(c(X201, 1:200))
input2 <- split(input, f= input$X201)

a = 0
b= 0
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(20)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)
tm1 <- system.time(
  y <- 
    foreach (h = length(input2),.combine = 'cbind') %:%
    foreach (j = nrow(input2[[h]]),.combine = 'c',packages = 'foreach') %dopar%{
      a = input2[[h]][j,3]
      b = b + a
    } 

)
parallel::stopCluster(cl)
registerDoSEQ()
print("Cluster stopped.")
```

y is about `0.55` (the exact value depends on the random number one generated), which is the value of `input2[[10]][20,3]`, not the accumulative value I desired. I checked the manual of the foreach package but still not sure I fully understand the mechanism of the foreach function.

Comment: Please include all non-base packages you are using. I'm inferring `dplyr`, `parallel`, and `foreach`, but please be explicit in the sample code.

Comment: Sure. I added the three libraries.

Comment: `foreach` basically works like `lapply`. It uses an expression instead of a function and also different syntax, but the principle is exactly the same, i.e., there are no side effects such as updating variables outside the loop. The required (by the bounty) official sources are the package vignettes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R foreach returns back results instead allows the outside variable to be changed. So don't expect a, b to be updated correctly.

Try the following

```
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(20)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)

tm2 <- system.time(
results <- foreach(h = (1:length(input2)), .combine = "c") %dopar%{
    sum( input2[[h]][1:nrow(input2[[h]]),3])
},
b <- sum(results[1:length(results)])
)
parallel::stopCluster(cl)
registerDoSEQ()
b
tm2
```